# cntk import Error /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cntk/libs/libCntk.Math-2.5.1.so: undefined symbol: LAPACKE_dgesvd

Tags: python, cntk

While importing `cntk` in python the following error is coming:

```
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/ubuntu/src/cntk/bindings/python/cntk/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import cntk_py
File "/home/ubuntu/src/cntk/bindings/python/cntk/cntk_py.py", line 21, in <module>
    _cntk_py = swig_import_helper()
File "/home/ubuntu/src/cntk/bindings/python/cntk/cntk_py.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_cntk_py')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cntk/libs/libCntk.Math-2.5.1.so: undefined symbol: LAPACKE_dgesvd
```

Installation procedure:

```
sudo apt-get install openmpi-bin
sudo pip3 install cntk-gpu
```

Comment: How did you install `cntk`?